# Задача на числовую последовательность

Tags: c++

[image: Вот задача]

Не понимаю как решать задачи с числовыми последовательностями и не могу найти нужной информации. Прошу кого-нибудь помочь. Вот код но только на ПаскалеАВС вроде как, а надо на с++ и чтобы объяснили.

```
uses crt;
var n:i integer;
k,c,s:real;
q:stribg;
begin
writeln('BBeguTe n ');
readln(n);
k:=1;
c:=0;
s:=0;
for i:=1 to n do 
begin
c:c+cos(i);
s:=s+sin(i);
k:=k*(c/s);
end;
writeln('Результат=',k:0:5);
writeln('Для выхода нажмите q');
readln(q);
until q='q';
end.
```

Comment: Циклами решать, циклами...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    size_t n = 0;

    cout << "n = ";
    cin >> n;
    
    double sinSum = 0;
    double cosSum = 0;
    double result = 1;

    for (size_t i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sinSum += sin(i);
        cosSum += cos(i);
        result *= sinSum / cosSum;
    }

    cout << "\nresult: " << result;
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Если уж `size_t i`, то для `n` этот тип надо выбрать и подавно :)

Comment: не обращаешь уже внимания, когда часто используешь сниппеты.. исправил

Comment: Neomaster, спасибо тебе :з